# Gallium Nitride SCR/Thyristor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, scr, gan

I have an application that requires switching on a load very fast (1ns or so).

There are N-channel / low side GaN MOSFETS. I would really like to switch a load on the high side, which causes problems when the FET output/"source" rises above the gate driver voltage.

I would really like to a find an ultra high speed switching SCR / Thyristor for this, but have been unable to find them.

Can anyone suggest a family of components I may want to look at?

Comment: Did you consider a snubber to suppress that due to your transition impedance Flyback?

Comment: why not use a floating gate drive to produce a gate voltage higher than the source when conducting. You will struggle to find a wide bandgap SCR since they are not really made

Comment: What is your dV/dt? dI/dt?

Comment: Thank you @JonRB. That's what I was looking for. I think we'll need to do the floating driver, was just thinking an SCR would be more convenient.